# Building a Fat jar with local dependencies Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have a build.gradle file as follows

```
buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:0.8.2'
    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:0.8.2'
}
```

When I run `gradle build` it downloads the dropwizard dependencies from maven repository and builds a fat jar. Every time I pull the code in a new development environment it fetches from the maven central repo. But some of the development machines do not have internet access, to build in these machines, I thought if I could create a folder called `libs` in the source code root folder and use this folder as to load the jar files, like

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}
```

Is it possible to do? Where to find the downloaded jars from maven central in my local machine, so that I can copy them into the libs folder (dropwizard 0.8.2 jar)

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Create the following task:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'libs'
}
```

After running this task you'll have a folder *libs* with all the dependencies (you might need a broader range than just *compile* - so align the task). You need to check this folder to SCM and commit it.

Of course mind the fact that it won't automatically update the dependencies if you e.g. change the version - you need to do it manually or maybe write a plugin that does all the things you need.

Comment: Hi i have added as you suggested, ran the task copyLibs , but I get the error `package io.dropwizard does not exist` when compiling

Comment: For downloading the libraries you need to add `repositories` block with `mavenCentral()` specified.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to add Mockito dependency but adding dependency like this is not working      `dependencies {   compile name: 'mockito-core-2.0.14-beta'
    compile name: 'mockito-all-1.9.5'}`

Comment: What do you mean by saying *not working*? Could you please share your `build.gradle` script?